# 403 forbidden error when changing s3 bucket files

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to host my website with amazon aws s3 static website hosting.

I created a bucket, completed permissions and the bucket policy etc.

And it was returning a 403 forbidden access when I tried to access my end point.

After leaving it for a weekend I went back to have another go and it was working.

Now I tried to delete the contents of the bucket and add some different files. ( basically the same just a few changes in some paragraphs.)

And once again it is now giving me a 403 forbidden access. My question is. Is there a waiting period or something when a bucket or it’s contents are changed. ?

Or is it just me doing something wrong. ? I didn’t change my policy or permissions so I don’t see why it has gone back to giving me a "403 forbidden" message again.

I have looked at previous questions and also aws documentation but couldn’t find anything specific to this.

Appreciate any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make all files public. You can either make them public using S3 console/interface or aws cli. It does not take any time to apply public rule, it will be applied instantly.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, this has solved my problem thank you for your response.